# SIGILL crashes my qt application, but I only see it clearly in debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I'm working on a qt5 application, using qtcreator 4.9.0. My application is crashing due to SIGILL, but that is not the main issue.

What I don't like is that if I launch it in debug mode, I can see it clearly displayed (I get a dialog telling me that the SIGILL signal was received).

If I just run it (NOT in debug mode) I can tell it's crashed, since the application stops working and the exit code is bad.
But i would also like to see the same dialog I see when in debug mode, or something similar.

Is it possible?

Edit:
Sorry, the question does lack details.

I am working in windows, using mingw. I am relying on SIGILL because I'm using the `-fsanitize=undefined` g++ switch, in order to trap undefined behaviors.

Since I don't have libubsan in my sistem, I also am using  `-fsanitize-undefined-trap-on-error`: this allows me to use the sanitizer without libubsan, but causes SIGILL to be raised.

So the signal is actually desired in my case, and I'm not debating on how to show it to the user, rather than to find a more convenient way for myself: I like that when the application crashes, a dialog appears, since it is very explicit.

When I say "in debug mode" I mean launching the application from the Debug menu, or simply by pressing F5: in this case I can clearly see the signal has been raised, since the "crash" dialog appears. If instead I just run the application (CTRL+R) I surely can tell the application isn't working: it kinda freezes and exits with an abnormal exit code, but that's it.
I mean, I can live with that, but it would be nice to see the dialog.

Comment: Have you tried installing custom handler, e.g. via sigaction or signal? See: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction EDIT: btw, what do you mean "debug mode" - compiled in debug mode, or executed under debugger's control?

Comment: The problem with showing debug confirmation dialogs in release builds is that it will confuse end-users. Such dialogs are for the developers when testing and diagnosing crashes.

Comment: @alagner make your comment a real answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: IMHO it depends on what the OP really desires to do. To me it's somewhat acceptable to check for some CPU capabilities at the start and fail fast if they're not available and request sth, e.g. a specific command line switch.

Comment: @alagner On Windows one usually get a special system "debug / ignore / crash" dialog when running debug builds. I interpret the question that the OP wants to display this system dialog in release builds as well. Which is different from catching a crash and displaying an application dialog just saying "program crashed".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude word `SIGILL` automatically rang the unix-like bell in my head. I'm not really familiar with Windows as a development platform, thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @alagner That's true, I didn't think too much about that part. Some clarification from the OP would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment a bit.
First, my assumption is that the platform is some unix-like system, SIGILL suggests that. No clue about Windows.
Second, I assume "debug mode" is "debug build", not "execution under debugger's control".

Given the above assertions are true:
The most natural way seems to be `signal` or `sigaction`.
See: https://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction

However, there is only a specific subset of functions one is allowed to call from a signal handler, so you might want to check on that first: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_01

Also, QT docs have some examples on how to deal with POSIX signals
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html

Last but not least, as it has already been mentioned in the comments:
be careful what you present to the user, from both the UX perspective as well as from the security standpoint.

In a regular case I'd probably either leave the signal unhadled, or abort in order to generate a core dump if this happens (don't recall if SIGILL does that by default).
Even better option might be to fail at application startup  and request the user to do whatever it's needed (fail fast, basically).
But again, "context is king" here and maybe due to security it's favourable not to generate any dumps and just fail as silently as possible, OP has to answer for him/herself here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude expanded that slightly.